# T-Sql Cartesian Join to Fill Dates and Join to CTE to Get Most Recent

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Our current method of calculating out of stock no longer works for how we track inventory and how we need to view the data. The new method I want to use is to only look at the final OnHandAfter value for each day in the trailing year. We are not 24/7 so the last value entered at the end of each day will tell us if the item was in/out of stock that day. **If an item has no inventory transactions for a date it should use the previous found date**.

- My current query does a cross join of all out items (I currently have
  it set to a single item for testing) and a calendar table. This give
  me 365 days for each item. This is working.
- My cte query returns the final OnHandAfter for each date there was a
  transaction. This is working *if run by itself*.
- With the <= date condition commented out I get 365 rows returned but
  dates from the cte are NULL. If the condition is not commented out 0
  rows are returned.
- Note, the next step is to include the OnHandAfter field but for now I
  can't seem to get the cte to connect.

ABDailyCalendar abdc
This is a table prefilled with every date in the trailing year

Sample Inventory Data (what the cte returns for single item if run by itself, I left out some columns for brevity)

```
ItemCode    TransactionDate OnHandAfter rn
Item-123    10/1/2018       960         1
Item-123    9/28/2018       985         1
Item-123    9/27/2018       1085        1
Item-123    9/26/2018       1485        1
Item-123    9/24/2018       1835        1
Item-123    9/20/2018       2035        1
Item-123    9/18/2018       2185        1
Item-123    9/14/2018       2305        1
Item-123    9/13/2018       2605        1
```

My Query

```
with cte as 
(
Select TOP 1 * from
(
    Select 
         ItemCode
        ,convert(Date,TransactionDate) TransactionDate
        ,TransactionType
        ,TransactionQuantity
        ,OnHandBefore
        ,OnHandAfter
        ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ItemCode, CONVERT(Date, TransactionDate) order by TransactionDate DESC) as rn
    from InventoryTransaction
    where TransactionType in (1,2,4,8)
) as ss
where rn = 1
order by TransactionDate DESC
)
SELECT 
     ab.ExternalId
    ,abdc.[Date]
    ,cte.TransactionDate
     From ABItems ab CROSS JOIN ABDailyCalendar abdc
     FULL OUTER JOIN cte on cte.ItemCode = ab.ExternalId --and cte.TransactionDate <= abdc.[Date]
Where ab.ExternalID = 'Item-123'
order by abdc.[Date] DESC
```

Current Sample Results

```
ExternalId  Date        TransactionDate
Item-123    9/30/2018   NULL
Item-123    9/29/2018   NULL
Item-123    9/28/2018   NULL
Item-123    9/27/2018   NULL
Item-123    9/26/2018   NULL
Item-123    9/25/2018   NULL
Item-123    9/24/2018   NULL
```

Desired Results

```
ExternalId  Date        TransactionDate
Item-123    9/30/2018   9/28/2018
Item-123    9/29/2018   9/28/2018
Item-123    9/28/2018   9/28/2018
Item-123    9/27/2018   9/27/2018
Item-123    9/26/2018   9/26/2018
Item-123    9/25/2018   9/24/2018
Item-123    9/24/2018   9/24/2018
```

The `TransactionDate` should be the most recent `TransactionDate` that is <= to the `Date`.

If it matters - I am running SSMS 2012 connected to SQL Server 2008.

Any pointers or ideas will be greatly appreciated. I have stared at it so long that nothing new is coming to me. Thanks.

Comment: Aside: Indexing may make a big difference in performance. What, if any, indexes do you have?

Comment: Why not try: Take all your transactions and rownumber them partitioned by externalid, order by transactiondate - as a cte. Join this to itself on cte1.rn = cte2.rn+1 (and externalid), to get rows of prev-date data and current-date data, then join this to your calendar table on calendar table's date is >= cte1.trandate and < cte2.trandate. you should  now have a row for every date together with the onhand on that date

Comment: @HABO - I am not too concerned with performance. Though not ideal, anything that takes under 30 minutes is workable. I will run this locally against a copy or our DB.

Comment: @CaiusJard, So far I am encountering a similar problem. As soon as I add < or > to the join condition 0 rows are returned. I have confirmed the calendar table has 365 days. Is there something special I have to do to join a Date to a DateTime? I tried converting both to dates but that didn't help.  I do like having another way of writing this query. Two options to tinker means I won't get mentally stuck in one query for too long.

Comment: are you sure that item code is same in both the table cte And ABItems may be it contains extra space which makes the join to fail and it put as null.select one more column from cte and see whether it is displaying as null.

Comment: @Mani, yes, if I remove the calendar table I can join the items and inventory tables on ItemCode/ExternalID

Answer (score 0):

I used postgres but it's broadly the same as SQLS for this operation. Here's an impl of what i wrote in my comment:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uKcgh9yZVvvqfRWTERv2a3/0

We make some sample data on the left side of the fiddle. This is PG specific but shouldn't matter too much - end result is it gets to the same place you are with your data in SQLS

Then the query:

```
SELECT 
  itemcode, 
  caldate, 
  case when caldate = transactiondate then onhandafter else prev_onhandafter end as onhandat,
  case when caldate = transactiondate then 'tran occurred today, using current onhandafter' else 'no tran today, using previous onhandafter' end as reasoning,
  transactiondate,
  onhandafter,
  prev_onhandafter

FROM
(
  SELECT 
    itemcode, 
    transactiondate, 
    LAG(transactiondate) over(partition by itemcode order by transactiondate) as prev_transactiondate,
    onhandafter,
    LAG(onhandafter) over(partition by itemcode order by transactiondate) as prev_onhandafter
  FROM 
    t
) t2
  INNER JOIN
  c
  ON 
    c.caldate > t2.prev_transactiondate and c.caldate <= t2.transactiondate
ORDER BY itemcode, caldate
```

itemcode/externalid (you called it both)

Bunch of dates - whether your dates are DATE or DATETIME they're comparable. No harm in casting a DATETIME to a DATE if you want, and if any of your dates contain a time component it may well be vital to do so, because 2018-01-01 **00**:00 is not the same as 2018-01-01 **01**:00, and if your calendar table has midnight, and the transactiondate is 1 am, then the range join condition (`caldate > prevtrandate and caldate <= trandate`) won't work out properly. Feel free to cast as part of the join: `caldate > CAST(prevtrandate as DATE) and caldate <= CAST(trandate as DATE)`. If your datetimes are 100% guaranteed to be exactly bang on midnight (to the microsecond) then the join will work out without casting - casting here is a quick trick to strip the time off and ensure apples are comparing to apples

OK, so how this works:

Rather than number the rows in the table in a cte and join it to itself I used a similar technique using LAG to get the previous row's values I'm interested in. Previous here is defined as "per item code, in ascending order of trandate". This gives us rows that have a current trandate, a previous trandate *(note: null for the first row, some extra fiddling with the query, like COALESCE(lag(...), trandate) will be required if it is to be kept otherwise it will disappear when joined)* a previous onhand. We''l use the date pair to join and we'll later choose whether to present the current or previous onhand.

This is done as a subquery so that the prev values become available to use. It is joined to the calendar table on the calendar date being greater than the prev trandate and less than or equal to the current trandate. This means that a cartesian product fills in all the gaps in the transaction dates so we get a contiguous set of dates out of the calendar table.

We use a case when to examine the data - if the cal date is equal to the tran date, we use the new value for onhand because a tran occurred today and decremented the stock. Otherwise we can assert that there was no transaction today, and we should use the prev onhand instead.

Hopefully this is all the right way round with regards to what you want (you seemed to indicate that it was onhandafter that you actually wanted, but your desired query output only mentioned the transaction date/caldate pair

Edit: ok, lag isn't available- here's a solution that uses rownumber:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2ooVrNF18stUQAa4HyTj6r/0

```
  WITH cte AS(
  SELECT 
    itemcode, 
    transactiondate, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by itemcode order by transactiondate) as rown,
    onhandafter
  FROM 
    t
)

SELECT 
  curr.itemcode, 
  c.caldate, 
  case when c.caldate = curr.transactiondate then curr.onhandafter else prev.onhandafter end as onhandat,
  case when c.caldate = curr.transactiondate then 'tran occurred today, using current onhandafter' else 'no tran today, using previous onhandafter' end as reasoning,
  curr.transactiondate,
  curr.onhandafter,
  prev.onhandafter

FROM
  cte curr
  INNER JOIN
  cte prev
  ON curr.rown = prev.rown + 1 and curr.itemcode = prev.itemcode
  INNER JOIN
  c
  ON 
    c.caldate > prev.transactiondate and c.caldate <= curr.transactiondate
  ORDER BY curr.itemcode, c.caldate
```

How it works: pretty much as my first comment. We partition the table into itemcode and rownumber in order of tran date. We do this as a cte so it's cleaner to say `from cte curr inner join cte prev on curr.rownumber = prev.rownumber+1`

Lag is thus simulated- we have a row that has current values and previous values. The rest of the query logic remains the same from above

Comment: Since I am querying off a 2008 server LAG is not available. I ike the structure of this query, already more readable than I had. I will see if I can replace the LAGs somehow and get it to work.

Comment: I do eventually want the OnHandAfter but figured that would be easy once I can get the join to join. Thanks.

Comment: Oof, nuisance. You did say that and I plain up didn't look up what was available sorry. I'll jig it around to Simulate lag